# Problem with creating a model in Qgis -- select by location

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder, select-by-location, qgis-modeler

I have two shapefiles (polygones) - referentiebestand and oudejaren

-> the first step is to calculate the centroids of each shapefile (gives a good result),
 then a create a buffer around one of this shapefiles, referentiebestand (gives a good result).

But then i receive a problem: The goal is find the points that lies outside the buffer,
I tried it with the tool 'Select by location' (see figure 1). But it gives nothing...
[image: select by location]

The complete model (figure 2)[image: Complete model]

If i use the tool 'select by location' outside the model, in the intergraph
And choose 'new selection' it select the points, so that works well.

[image]

But when i choose 'remove selection' instead of new selection the result is empty, nothing changed...

When i try 'new selection' 'add to current selection' or 'remove selection' , nothing changed...

Comment: Does it work if you do those processes individually (ie. via the QGIS interface)? If it does then we can narrow down the issue being connected to the modeler.

Comment: I just noticed that when you use the _Select by location_ function, you are selecting to **remove** the selected features. You then use the _Save selected features_ which would have been removed previously. Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: Via the interface -> the option new selection is worked, but not the option remove selection. In the model nothing works of the options.., also when a deactive the tool 'save selected features'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to save to points outside the buffers, I would recommend to use the **Difference** operator instead of select and then save.

Of course it's still interesting to check if select by location works correctly in models but it's not necessary for this use case  I think.

---

Update:

Try setting the input of Save selected features to be the output of the buffering operation.

[image]

If I interpret the behavior correctly, the output of select by location makes no sense since it does not actually contain the selected features.

I've tried to fix the script: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/1921

Comment: Thanks, With the tool Difference its works and i receive my expected result.
But for the tool 'select by location'. How is it possible to setting the input of Save selected features to be the output of the buffering operation? Because it looks me impossible to connect the input of a tool with the output of another tool...

Comment: I know it sounds weird. Maybe try the fixed version of the select by location tool. (Just replace your local copy with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qgis/QGIS/8d87f353041a410fc2decdea7bd488f3a12888e7/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SelectByLocation.py)